# FFmpeg: How can I hstack two videos, and scale just one up with scale_cuda?

Tags: ffmpeg, cuda

This is a command I used that worked with `scale_npp` instead of `scale_cuda`

`ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i "Input1.mkv" -c:v h264_cuvid -i "Input2.mkv" -c:v h264_nvenc -filter_complex "hwupload_cuda,[0:v]scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos;[0v][1:v]hstack,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" "output.mkv" -y`

But with `scale_cuda`, the output says this:

`[AVFilterGraph @ 0x565389e2a780] Too many inputs specified for the "scale_cuda" filter`

But this command, which only involves upscaling and with only 1 video works:

`ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i "Input1.mkv" -c:v h264_nvenc -filter_complex "hwupload_cuda,scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" "output.mkv" -y`

What would be the correct way to do that 1st command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command should work:

`ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i "Input1.mkv" -c:v h264_cuvid -i "Input2.mkv" -filter_complex "[0:v]hwupload_cuda,scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080:format=nv12:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload[0v];[0v][1:v]hstack" -c:v h264_nvenc "output.mkv" -y`

---

- `[0:v]hwupload_cuda`, upload the video stream of Input1.mkv to the GPU.
- `hwdownload[0v]`, downloads the scaled video from the GPU, and gives it the temporary name `[0v]`.
  We have to download the video from the GPU before applying `hstack`, because `hstack` filter cannot be CUDA accelerated.
  The selected format is `nv12`, for matching the format of (decoded) Input2.mkv.

---

Testing:

- Build synthetic input files (for testing):
  `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p Input1.mkv`
  `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1920x1080:rate=1:duration=10 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p Input2.mkv`
- Executing the above command.

It's also working without `format=nv12`:

`ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i "Input1.mkv" -c:v h264_cuvid -i "Input2.mkv" -filter_complex "[0:v]hwupload_cuda,scale_cuda=w=1920:h=1080:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload[0v];[0v][1:v]hstack" -c:v h264_nvenc "output.mkv" -y`

Comment: The command works, thanks!